# Query not working in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, subquery

Why is this not working in SQLite but in MySQL?
Would be great if you help me!

Other question: Can I replace the Subselect with a Join?

```
SELECT h1.drivers.name, SUM((
    SELECT kilometers FROM history AS h2
    WHERE h2.timestamp >= h1.timestamp
    AND h1.id != h2.id
    GROUP BY h2.timestamp HAVING MIN(h2.timestamp) LIMIT 1
    ) - h1.kilometers) AS driven_kilometers
FROM history AS h1
INNER JOIN drivers ON drivers.id = h1.driver_id
GROUP BY h1.driver_id
```

To clearify my question:

```
╔════╦═════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ id ║driver_id║      timestamp      ║ kilometers    ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║  1 ║    1    ║ 2018-07-01 12:00:04 ║             0 ║
║  2 ║    2    ║ 2018-07-01 16:05:12 ║           120 ║
║  3 ║    1    ║ 2018-07-06 11:13:59 ║           220 ║
║  4 ║    2    ║ 2018-07-09 09:17:19 ║           250 ║
║  5 ║    1    ║ 2018-07-12 10:02:00 ║           300 ║
║  6 ║    2    ║ 2018-07-16 07:11:21 ║           320 ║
╚════╩═════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

I want to count driven kilometers.
The drivers will add a dataset when they start to drive so they will insert the kilometers driven by the other person.

Example: Kilometers for driver 2
I want to calculate: 220-120 + 300-250 = 150

Kilometers for driver 1:
I want to calculate: 120-0 + 250-220 + 320-300 = 170

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? "HAVING MIN()" is not valid SQL, so this query is not guaranteed to return something useful in any case. What do you actually want to do? Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Comment: The first error I get is, that h1.drivers.name is not found.

Comment: Why are you comparing both `id` and `timestamp`? And why is there no timestamp in the example data? Is the `id` guaranteed to be incrementing?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to insert the timestamp in my example. I'll insert it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the subquery, grouping does not make sense because the timestamp are unique anyway.

To get the value from the row with the next largest timestamp, just use ORDER BY with LIMIT:

```
SELECT drivers.name,
       SUM((SELECT kilometers
            FROM history AS h2
            WHERE h2.timestamp > h1.timestamp
            ORDER BY h2.timestamp 
            LIMIT 1
           ) - h1.kilometers
          ) AS driven_kilometers
FROM history AS h1
INNER JOIN drivers ON drivers.id = h1.driver_id
GROUP BY h1.driver_id;
```